# Hadoop Cluster deployment using Apache Ambari

Tags: apache, hadoop

I have listed few queries related to ambari as follows:

1. Can I configure more than one hadoop cluster via UI of ambari ? 
   ( Note : I am using Ambari 1.6.1 for my hadoop cluster deployment purpose and I am aware that this can be done via Ambari API, but not able to find via ambari portal)
2. We can check the status of services on each node by “jps” command, if we have configured hadoop cluster w/o ambari.
   Is there any way similar to “jps” to check from back end if the setup for hadoop cluster was successful from the backend ?
   ( Note : I can see that services are showing UP on the ambari portal )

Help Appreciated !!

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ambari UI is served up by the ambari server for a specific cluster.  To configure another cluster you need to point your browser to the URL for that other cluster's ambari server.  So you can't see the configuration for multiple servers on the same web page, but you can set browser bookmarks to jump from configuration to configuration.